# SendKeys(Keys.Enter) not working in Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have entered text in a text box. And now I want to press Enter key. To do that, I am passing `sendKey(Keys.Enter)` which just cut the text from the text box and does nothing.

```
 driver.findMobileElement("id", setLocationTextBoxId).sendKeys(parkingLocation+"\n");
 driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Note: `"\n"` is not working already. `sendKeyEvent/pressKeyEvent` method is not available.

Comment: Better use Actions class to perform the Keys.ENTER keypress.

Comment: Please elaborate how to use.

Comment: Why is this down voted. Can anybody please answer? This is not duplicate. This is a programming question. People are unable to answer. Then why down vote. I really don't understand, what's happening on Stack Over flow.

Answer (score 0):

To press **ENTER** key on Android device, you need to use Android KeyEvent codes. The key code for ENTER is **66**. You can use the below code snippet.

```
driver.longPressKeyCode(66);
```

To get the all Android KeyEvent codes please refer this official [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)

Comment: Did you try it. It isn't working for me. Moreover the link you mentioned is for Android and not for appium driver.

Comment: @DhirajAggarwal Yes. It works for me. I have been using this from last one year. And FYI, appium internally uses Android's UIAutomatotar to send commands to device. As you are mentioning its for Android and not for appium, IT IS FOR APPIUM with ANDROID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! I have the same problem like you, and i got frustated untill i found this. Hope this will help you out!

```
    public void pressEnterEditText(String elementName, String value) {
    AndroidElement tempElement = getAndroidElement(elementName);
    tempElement.click();
    driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
}
```